# Populating Custom merge fields into Docusign template using Embedded Signing

Tags: docusignapi

In Salesforce Community, we are using Embedded Signing using Docusign Connect for the clients to sign the documents. We are having issue in populating the merge fields in the template. We are trying to use DocuSignAPI.CustomField and DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField but unable to do so. Could someone please look into the code and help us identify the issue? Thank you!

```
    /*=====================================================================
SendToDocuSignController 
=====================================================================*/

public without sharing class SendToDocuSignController {
    private final list<Contact> lstcontact ;
    private final Application__c objApplication;
    private final list<DocuSign_Lease_Mapping__c> lstDocuSignLeaseMapping;
    private final list<AddOns__c> lstAddOns;
    Private static string trace_value = 'SFDC_002_SOAP_sender_view'; // Used for tracing API calls
    Private static string trace_key = 'X-ray'; 

   // Demo code
    Public string sender_view_url {get;set;} 
    Public string sender_return_url {get;set;} // Required. Where DS redirects to after sending 
    Public string signer_email {get;set;}   // Required
    Public string signer_name {get;set;}    // Required
    Public string email_message {get;set;}  // Optional
    Public string output {get;set;}
    Public string error_code {get;set;} // Null means no error
    Public string error_message {get;set;}
 // Demo code
    public String envelopeId {get;set;}
    private Constants__c objConstantSetting = Constants__c.getOrgDefaults();
    private String accountId = 'd66c97b3-f210-41c5-8dcc-1c617d4431d8';  //'3753234'
    private String userId = objConstantSetting.Docusign_User_ID__c;
    private String password = objConstantSetting.Docusign_Password__c;
    private String integratorsKey = objConstantSetting.Docusign_Integrator_Key__c;
    private String webServiceUrl = objConstantSetting.Docusign_webServiceUrl__c;

    public SendToDocuSignController()
    {
        System.debug('lstcontact');
        String ApplicationID = 'a070t000000EF9Y';  //a070t000000MBpi 
        this.lstAddOns = [SELECT Id ,Name ,Application__c FROM AddOns__c where Application__c =:ApplicationID ];
        this.objApplication = [select Id, Household__c, Property__c  from Application__c where id = :ApplicationID ];
        this.lstcontact = [select Id, Name, RecordType.Name , Email from Contact where RecordType.Name != 'Minor Child' AND Email !=  null AND AccountId =:objApplication.Household__c ];
        System.debug('lstcontact'+lstcontact);
        if(lstAddOns.isEmpty())
        this.lstDocuSignLeaseMapping  = [select DocuSign_Template_ID__c, Name, Property__c from DocuSign_Lease_Mapping__c where Property__c =: objApplication.Property__c ];
        else
        this.lstDocuSignLeaseMapping  = [select DocuSign_Template_ID__c, Name, Property__c from DocuSign_Lease_Mapping__c where Property__c =: objApplication.Property__c AND   Concession_Addendum__c = false];
        envelopeId = 'Not sent yet';  
    }

    /*****************************************************************
    Method Name : SendNow()
    Purpose: Creates Docusign envelope and sends an email from docusign to sign the docs

    ******************************************************************/
    public PageReference SendNow()
    {
        DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap dsApiSend = new DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap();
        dsApiSend.endpoint_x = webServiceUrl;
        //Set Authentication
        String auth = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>'+ userId 
            +'</Username><Password>' + password 
            + '</Password><IntegratorKey>' + integratorsKey 
            + '</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';
        System.debug('Setting authentication to: ' + auth);

        dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
        dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('X-DocuSign-Authentication', auth);
        dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x.put(trace_key, trace_value);

        //Create Docusign envelope information object 
        DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeInformation EnvelopeInformation = new DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeInformation ();
        EnvelopeInformation.Subject = Label.Docusign_Email_Subject ;
        EnvelopeInformation.EmailBlurb = ' ';
        EnvelopeInformation.AccountId  = objConstantSetting.Docusign_Account_ID__c; 
        System.debug('EnvelopeInformation'+EnvelopeInformation);

        DocuSignAPI.CustomField field = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField (); 
        field.Name = 'DSFSSourceObjectId'; //'dsfs__Application__c'; 
        field.Value = 'a070t000000EF9Y'; //'01I0t0000000FK3'; 
        field.Show = 'true';
        field.CustomFieldType = 'Text';
        DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField arrayOfCustomField = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField();
        arrayOfCustomField.CustomField  = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField[1];
        arrayOfCustomField.CustomField[0] = field;
        EnvelopeInformation.CustomFields = arrayOfCustomField;
        System.debug('PB: field.Name & field.value = '+ field.Name +field.value);

        //Create Docusign TemplateReference object 
        DocusignAPI.TemplateReference reference = new DocusignAPI.TemplateReference();
        DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTemplateReference templateReferenceArray = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTemplateReference();
        templateReferenceArray.TemplateReference = new DocuSignAPI.TemplateReference[lstDocuSignLeaseMapping.size()];
        System.debug('lst of template'+lstDocuSignLeaseMapping);
        System.debug('lst of lstDocuSignLeaseMapping.size()'+lstDocuSignLeaseMapping.size());


        Integer seq =0;
        Integer index = 0;
        Integer signerNumber = 1;
        //Create Docusign recipient object
        DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
        DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1 Recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient1();
        Recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[lstcontact.size()];


        DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment roleAssignment1; 
        DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment roleAssignment2; 

        for(Contact objcontact : lstcontact) {

            recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
            recipient.ID = signerNumber;
            recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
            recipient.roleName = 'Signer ' + String.valueOf(signerNumber);
            recipient.RoutingOrder = signerNumber;
            recipient.Email = objcontact.Email; 
            recipient.UserName = objcontact.Name ;           
            recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;
            recipient.CaptiveInfo = new DocuSignAPI.RecipientCaptiveInfo(); 
            recipient.CaptiveInfo.ClientUserId = objcontact.Id;
            System.debug('recipient'+recipient); 
            Recipients.Recipient[seq] = recipient;

            if(signerNumber == 1) {
                roleAssignment1 = new  DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
            roleAssignment1.RoleName = recipient.RoleName;
                roleAssignment1.RecipientID = recipient.ID;
            }
            if(signerNumber == 2) {
                roleAssignment2 = new  DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
            roleAssignment2.RoleName = recipient.RoleName;
             roleAssignment2.RecipientID = recipient.ID;
            }
            signerNumber++;
            seq++;
        } 
        seq = 1;


        for(DocuSign_Lease_Mapping__c objDocuSignLeaseMapping : lstDocuSignLeaseMapping){
            reference = new DocusignAPI.TemplateReference();

            reference.TemplateLocation = 'Server';
            reference.Template =  objDocuSignLeaseMapping.DocuSign_Template_ID__c;

            reference.sequence = seq;  
            reference.RoleAssignments = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
            reference.RoleAssignments.RoleAssignment = new DocuSignAPI.TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment[3];
            reference.RoleAssignments.RoleAssignment[0] = roleAssignment1;
            reference.RoleAssignments.RoleAssignment[1] = roleAssignment2;
            templateReferenceArray.TemplateReference[index] = reference;
            index++;
            seq++;
        }


        //create and send envelope with template
        try {
            //DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es1 = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(EnvelopeInformation);
            DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es 
            = dsApiSend.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(templateReferenceArray, Recipients ,EnvelopeInformation,true);
            envelopeId = es.EnvelopeID;

            DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs clientURLs = new DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs();
            Blob b = Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
            String h = EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
            String guid = h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
            DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertion assertion = new DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertion();
            assertion.AssertionID = guid;
            assertion.AuthenticationInstant = DateTime.Now();
            assertion.AuthenticationMethod = 'Email';
            assertion.SecurityDomain = 'force.com';
            // Construct the URLs based on username
            DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs urls = new DocuSignAPI.RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs();
            String urlBase = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+lstcontact[0].id ;
            clientURLs.OnSigningComplete = urlBase + '?event=SignComplete&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnViewingComplete = urlBase + '?event=ViewComplete&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnCancel = urlBase + '?event=Cancel&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnDecline = urlBase + '?event=Decline&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnSessionTimeout = urlBase + '?event=Timeout&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnTTLExpired = urlBase + '?event=TTLExpired&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnIdCheckFailed = urlBase + '?event=IDCheck&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnAccessCodeFailed = urlBase + '?event=AccessCode&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            clientURLs.OnException = urlBase + '?event=Exception&uname=' + recipient.UserName;
            // assumes apiService = preconfigured api proxy
            String token;
        try {

            token = dsApiSend.RequestRecipientToken(envelopeId,Recipients.Recipient[0].captiveinfo.ClientUserId,Recipients.Recipient[0].UserName,Recipients.Recipient[0].Email,assertion,clientURLs);
            String token1 = dsApiSend.RequestRecipientToken(envelopeId,Recipients.Recipient[1].captiveinfo.ClientUserId,Recipients.Recipient[1].UserName,Recipients.Recipient[1].Email,assertion,clientURLs);
            system.debug('????????????token1??????????' + token1);

        }
          catch ( CalloutException e) {
                System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
                envelopeId = 'Exception - ' + e;
        }
            PageReference retURL = new PageReference(token);
            retURL.setRedirect(false);
            return retURL;
    }
        catch ( CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
            envelopeId = 'Exception - ' + e;
            return null;
        }

    }
        private String getPopURL() {
        String popURL = String.valueOf(System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl());
        if (popURL == null) {
            popURL = 'https://na3.salesforce.com/apex/';
        } 
        System.Debug('pop page: ' + popURL + 'embedPop');
        return popURL + 'embedPop';
    }
}
```